# How to make a custom command line interface using OptionParser?

Tags: python, optparse

I am using the OptionParser from optparse module to parse my command that I get using the raw_input().

I have these questions.

1.) I use OptionParser to parse this input, say for eg.  (getting multiple args)

```
my prompt> -a foo -b bar -c spam eggs
```

I did this with setting the action='store_true' in add_option() for '-c',now if there is another option with multiple argument say -d x y z then how to know which arguments come from which option? also if one of the arguments has to be parsed again like

```
my prompt> -a foo -b bar -c spam '-f anotheroption'
```

2.) if i wanted to do something like this..

```
my prompt> -a foo -b bar 
my prompt> -c spam eggs 
my prompt> -d x y z
```

now each entry must not affect the other options set by the previous command. how to accomplish these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part 2: you want a new OptionParser instance for each line you process.  And look at the [cmd module](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd) for writing a command loop like this.

Comment: wow! thanx.. i din't know python had a builtin library for these kind of stuff.. but still there are no examples provided in the doc. :(

Comment: cmd is awesome... now i am trying to insert OptionParser into the processing of a command in the custom command line UI..

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve #1 using the `nargs` option attribute as follows:

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-c", "", nargs=2)
parser.add_option("-d", "", nargs=3)
```

Comment: it helped a bit but how can i say what arguments are for what options as all the arguments end up on the same list

Comment: got it! sexy!
yes now i get a tuple for the arguments.. this is what i wanted.. and 'store_true' must not be used with nargs option... :)

Answer (score 1):

`optparse` solves #1 by requiring that an argument always have the same number of [parameters](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.nargs) (even if that number is 0), variable-parameter arguments are not allowed:

> Typically, a given option either takes
>   an argument or it doesn’t. Lots of
>   people want an “optional option
>   arguments” feature, meaning that some
>   options will take an argument if they
>   see it, and won’t if they don’t. This
>   is somewhat controversial, because it
>   makes parsing ambiguous: if "-a" takes
>   an optional argument and "-b" is
>   another option entirely, how do we
>   interpret "-ab"? Because of this
>   ambiguity, optparse does not support
>   this feature.

You would solve #2 by not reusing the previous values to [`parse_args`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#parsing-arguments), so it would create a new values object rather than update.

Comment: Of course, I also agree you shouldn't use optparse where cmd is more appropriate, but here is how optparse works!

Comment: thanx for the part two of the 1s question..
i know there is a way to handle multiple argument option but, i want to know how to manage multiple options with multiple arguments. it can be done by using 'store_true'. but still all the aruguments go into the same args list, and no reference for which function it belongs :(

Comment: If an option takes arguments, you need to specify nargs for it, then those won't be saved in 'args'.

Comment: yes now i get a tuple for the arguments.. this is what i wanted.. and 'store_true' must not be used with nargs option...